# How can i add a function ''Fly to a marker'' to an existing button? [Leaflet maps]

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, leaflet

I am trying to add a function fly to a marker on a button.
I have created some buttons, on the right, and i would like to add this function to one button.

```
 var latlng = map.getCenter(); // or [47.478058, 9.720154]
var marker = L.marker(latlng).addTo(map);
L.DomEvent.on(button,'click',function(){
    var zoomlvl = 16;
    map.flyTo(marker.getLatLng(),zoomlvl)
});
```

I just want to add this to my code --> https://jsfiddle.net/paulito92/p92sfz7o/1/
On the Availability Zones button for exemple.
I would like when i click on the button, that the map go on this specific location [48.6333, 2.2333]
I always face problem when i try to add the function.

If anyone know how to make it it would be sooo nice!

Thanks everybody, have a good day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the buttons event to the end of the script or after the marker creation. Also you have to use the variable `myDataPoint` instead the undefined variable `marker`

```
  
  var button = document.getElementById('availability')
L.DomEvent.on(button,'click',function(e){
    console.log('Button clicked')
});

L.DomEvent.on(button,'click',function(){
    var zoomlvl = 16;
    map.flyTo(myDataPoint.getLatLng(),zoomlvl)
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/f3etmzjn/